# How to find the equilibrium of the following stochastic game (numerically)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, game-theory

I build up a stochastic game with two groups of players (Group A and Group B) and within each group, the players can have two labels as H and L (label of each player may change from period to period). Each player (regardless of her group) can take two actions (1 or 0) at any time. The time $T=0,1,2,...$, discrete time horizon. Each group contains $N$ people (one can think $N$ being large).

The game is played as the following: at $t=0$, the fraction of people within each group with label H is given as initial condition. At the beginning of each period, people from group A and B are randomly re-matching to form $N$ pairs. Within each pair, both parties observe the label vector $r=(r^A,r^B)$, then both parties have to simultaneously take action (either 1 or 0).

If both parties take action 1, then the people in group A within this pair gets reward $R=f(r^B)$ and the people in group B within this pair gets reward $R=f(r^A)$ and $f(H)>f(L)$. Then the label of the two people in this pair will change according to a given transition matrix

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}\triangleq\begin{array}{ccccc}
~&(H,H)&(H,L)&(L,H)&(L,L)\\
(H,H)&p_{11}&p_{12}&p_{13}&p_{14}\\
(H,L)&p_{21}&p_{22}&p_{23}&p_{24}\\
(L,H)&p_{31}&p_{32}&p_{33}&p_{34}\\
(L,L)&p_{41}&p_{42}&p_{43}&p_{44}\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}

If either party take action 0, then neither parties will get any reward and their label remains unchanged and carry over to the next period.

The objective of each player (in either group) is to maximize her total expected discounted reward over infinite time horizon. The discount factor is $\delta\in(0,1)$.

The key of this game is that: it is just like two players solving a Markov Decision Process (MDP), but the two MDPs are linked since the decision of each pair will affect the distribution of the H label players within each group in the next period and this will in turn affects the probability that each player encountering an H player in the next period.

Though this game looks simple, I couldn't even figure out how to compute the equilibrium strategy numerically needless to say solving this game analytically. What I could do is to fix the strategy of group A people and group B people, then I run a simulation. A strategy that I used in the simulation has the form: "if my label is H, what should I do when facing H or L; if my label is L, what should I do when facing H or L". The equilibrium strategy may or may not have this form.

Any suggestion about numerically (or analytically?) solving this game is appreciated.

Comment: Since the players are small (atomistic), isn't it simply the solution of a static game (played over and over)? Moreover, they never meet again, which makes it looks even more as a static game. I am probably missing something.

Comment: @Pcw. The idea is the following: think about in period 0, there are 50% of group A player with label H and 30% of group B player with label H. Then let's say group A player always choose 1 and group B player only choose 1 when his label is H and the counterpart's label is H in his pair and if his label is L, he always choose 0. Then you know that only gonna be less than 100% of pairs reach a "deal", then according to the transition matrix, the distribution of group A (and B) player with label H will change in period 1

Comment: @Pcw. which means any focal player will have different probability of encountering the other group of player with label H from period to period. Hence, when he compute the expected total discounted reward before the game starts so as to figure out the best strategy, the expectation is very complicated, since it changes over time and depends on the strategy of both group of people. So how the change of the focal player's label only depends on the transition matrix, but the probability of the other party he will meet in the future depends on the collective action

Comment: What do players observe? And shouldn't strategies depend also at leat on the distribution of Hs and Ls?

Comment: @Michael The player only observe the label pair in his/her matching pair. I think the distribution of H within each group evolves in a deterministic way when N goes to infinity. So with the initial condition, the player should be able to derive the evolution of the distribution of H within each group at any time for any fixed strategy

Comment: @FTXX You make a restriction of allowable strategies and I do not see how this restriction is justified.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I thought the strategy I used is pure and stationary strategy. Are you suggesting that there could be mixed and history dependent strategy? Sorry, the strategy I said in the OP is an example. I really want to know how to compute the equilibrium strategy, which could be anything. I will change my OP

Comment: @FTXX It is a standard result that you can restrict yourself to stationary strategies in a stochastic games, where stationary strategies are strategies that depend only on states and states make the game stationary. But the states in your game are the whole distribution of types and your strategies do not depend on this distribution. If everyone ele uses strategies of the kind you specified. the decison problem of a player will in general not be stationary.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I am very new to stochastic games, I am not sure I understand you. So what do you mean by the states make the game stationary? So in my case, as you said, the system state is the distribution of H label within each group (i.e., 2 numbers between 0 and 1), are you saying the "stationary strategy" will make these 2 distributions (i.e., 2 numbers) become a constant? e.g., under the "stationary strategy", the H label fraction in group A is always 0.4, and the H label fraction in group B is always 0.8, sth. like that?

Comment: No, but "stationary strategies" usually mean strategies that are functions of the state. Your class of strategies does not have the property that when everyone uses such strategies, each players decision problem is a Markov decision problem. So what you do is different from what people usually do in stochastic games.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker why it is not an MDP? let's say player only observe the (H,L) pair, i.e., using my original strategy, then when a "deal" occurs, the focal player's label will change according to P matrix, and the label of the other party he can meet in the next period also changes right? and that probability depends on the distribution of H labels in the other group, which is a consequence of all players' strategy. I agree that my strategy is not stationary in the usual sense, but the decision problem is still MDP (what I confused myself is that I have system state and individual state)

Comment: @FTXX The decision problem will be stationary with the states being distributions, but you do not allow your startegies to depend on these solutions. Whether action 1 or 0 is optimal will in general not just depend on the types of the pair selected but the distribution.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Ok, then if I allow the strategy to depend on both the label pair for the current matching pair and also the system state, i.e., the fraction of H labels within each group (e.g., a central planner always announce these 2 fractions at the beginning of each period), then how to compute at least numerically the equilibrium strategy?